# Parse a response text to json object

Tags: python, json

I am hitting an api endpoint using python requests to get some data and here is my template of my response.text(Actual response contains millions of event objects)

```
{"event":"Session","properties":{"time":"1642145186", "distinct_id":"ABC-123", "Region":"EU"}}
{"event":"Login","properties":{"time":"1642125126", "distinct_id":"ABC-123", "Region":"EU"}}
{"event":"Register","properties":{"time":"16432125126", "distinct_id":"ABC-123", "Region":"EU"}}
```

When I try to convert my response.text to json object using `response.json()` or `json.loads(json.dumps(response.text))` it throws the following error

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data:
```

I do understand why it is throwing that error as the response.text is not in the right format what JSON object need to be and I would like to convert that text into a json object. Is it something we can do with regex so we can add a `comma` at the end of each line(I am newbie with Regex concept)? Or any other option? I would really appreciate some help here.

Comment: if its ndjson format you can use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67736164/convert-ndjson-to-json-in-python

Comment: I did not know that format is called ndjson or something like that existed. Thanks for teaching me something new today. That worked @TomášŠturm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That data is ndjson.

[The spec says](https://github.com/ndjson/ndjson-spec):

> Each JSON text MUST conform to the [RFC7159] standard and MUST be written to the stream followed by the newline character `\n` (0x0A). The newline character MAY be preceded by a carriage return `\r` (0x0D). **The JSON texts MUST NOT contain newlines or carriage returns.**

Since the delimeter is a newline you should split on newlines and decode each object individually.